# React app seems to crash on Safari and disables JavaScript Console

Tags: ios, reactjs, safari, console, crash

I wish I could tell you what the error is on the console, but my React app seems to be freezing up all functionality on the Safari browser.

The MAC JavaScript console doesn't work.  Actually, none of the 'Develop' commands works in my attempt to debug this issue (but only when I'm on my site).

Here's my deployed site.  https://global-covid-19-tracker.herokuapp.com

You've probably heard this many times..."It works fine on Chrome and IE", but gets choked up on Safari and iOS devices.

That seems to be my issue here, but at a grander scale since I can't even open up the JavaScript console to debug the issue.

It's not a Mac issue.  The app works fine on my Mac Internet Explorer browser.

I've googled this issue for hours and the only results I'm getting are instructions on how to open the Developer console.  I already know how to do that.

My Problem is:  My React app has disabled my Developer Console.

Any assistance would be GREATLY appreciated.  Please and Thank You!

Comment: Your React app is sending an infinite amount of API requests to `/daily` clogging up a lot of resources. Try disabling the API request and observe that it no longer freezes. You might want to add a timer for your API requests to occur once every X amount of time to prevent this from happening again.

Comment: Thanks, Nick!  That points me in the right direction.  Your response led me to search and find this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48601813/how-to-call-an-api-every-minute-for-a-dashboard-in-react).  From there, I added a timer (setInterval) to my API call in the App.js file.  After pushing those changes, my Safari browser actually works and I can open the developer console.  Although, I'm not sure the setInterval method is the resolution at this point because now my site is reloading every 30 seconds.  Any idea on where I should add the API timer?  Maybe the API index file?